# How to capture the screen after evaluate in casperjs?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Here is my code:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["jquery.js"]
});
var URL = casper.cli.get(0);
casper.start(URL, function (){
 casper.evaluate(function() {
     $(".tm-price").html("123");

});

});
casper.then(function(){
this.capture('nn.png');
});

casper.run();
```

I wanna to change the ".tm-price"'s html to "123",and then capture the screen.
How ever after run it ,it only capture the screen before I change it,but not after I change it.
What's wrong with my code.Would you please help me?Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find out if the price is already there or you must wait for it to get filled.

This real world example works for me with no problem:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    clientScripts: ["js/jquery.min.js"],
    viewportSize: {
        width: 1024,
        height: 768
    }
});

casper.start('http://stackoverflow.com', function() {
    casper.evaluate(function() {
        jQuery('#h-top-questions').html('Not Top Questions!');
    });
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('capture.png', {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: 1024,
        height: 1000
    });
});

casper.run();
```